# UIButton inside expandable UITableViewCell doesn't dissapear

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, expandable-table

I have UITableViewCell that becomes invisible by setting its height to zero:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return isCollapsed ? 0 : 50
}
```

Inside that cell I constraint every view from top to bottom of cell's view. And every view except UIButton works. But UIButton text doesn't disappear when cell's height is zero. I think it has to do with UIButton text not depending on parent height. UIButton background color does disappear when cell is collapsed.
Best solution that I found is to use UILabel instead. But it doesn't have touch animation. Is there another solution without manually hiding the button?

Comment: trying calling `layoutIfNeeded()`

Comment: can you share screenshot ?

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 3.0**

`UIButton` is subclass of `UILabel`. If your set hight to zero of button, but `UILabel` hight is not zero.You need to hidden that button. then its not appear in cell while hight of `cell` is zero.

```
cell.btn.isHidden = true
```

Comment: `UIButton` is not a subclass of `UILabel`. A button has a label as a subview.

Answer (score 0):

When you are making the height of the cell is 0 then, the subviews remains their height as assigned before. So, the subviews also have to remove from the cell or have to make their alpha 0.

try like:

```
cell.contentView.removeFromSuperview()
```

or,

```
cell.contentView.alpha = 0
```

or,

Make alpha zero (or remove) the subviews of the cell by taking them individually.